# A question on a property of definite integrals that $\int_a^b f(x)dx =\int_a^b f(a+b-x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I was asked to integrate $f(x)= \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\tan(x)} }$ from $\frac{\pi}{6}$ to $\frac{\pi}{3}$
so I used
$$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx =\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ dx$$
however, that gives
$$I= \large\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}  \normalsize{\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{6}-x\right)} }}$$which doesn't help.
My book has simply expressed this as
$$ \int_\frac{\pi}{3}^\frac{\pi}{6}\frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\cot(x)} }$$
and I'm unable to understand why , could someone help, please?

Comment: You replaced the constant $1$ in the denominator by $\pi/2 - 1$, which is wrong.

Comment: I just used the property, why is that wrong?

Comment: How did you get $\frac {\pi} 2-1$ in the denominator? $f(a+b-x)$ simply means you have to replace $x$ by $a+b-x$ in  the formula for $f(x)$. How does the constant $1$ in the denominator change?

Comment: or should it have been $\frac{\pi}{2}$- the original integrand ?

Comment: If $f(x)= \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\tan(x)} }$ then $f(\pi/2 - x)= \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\tan(\pi/2-x)} }= \frac{dx}{1+\sqrt{\cot(x)} }$.

Comment: @geetha290krm, I thought it meant (a+b)- the entire function. Thanks for clearing that !

Comment: @MartinR, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$I=\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{(\tan(x)}}dx$$
Using the substitution $t=({\frac{\pi}{3} + \frac{\pi}{6}})-x=\frac{\pi}{2}-x\implies dt=-dx$
$$I=\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{1}{1+\sqrt\cot(t)}dt=\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}\frac{\sqrt\tan(t)}{1+\sqrt\tan(t)}dt$$
Adding the two representations of $I$:
$$2I(a)=\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}dt=\frac{\pi}{3} -\frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{\pi}{6}$$
Solving for $I$:
$$I=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: Do you miss the square root sign?

Comment: @Lai yeah it was a typo , thanks for noticing it i will update it soon

Comment: It’s my pleasure. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d x}{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}\stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{\pi}{2}-x}{=} \int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d x}{1+\sqrt{\cot x}} 
=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{d x}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\tan x}}} =\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{\sqrt{\tan x}+1} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 I&=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}}\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}+\frac{\sqrt{\tan x}}{1+\sqrt{\tan x}}\right) d x=\int_{\frac{\pi}{6}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} 1 d x =\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore we can conclude that $$I=\frac{\pi}{12}$$

Comment: thanks a lot!!!